# Python - Packages Install

Tags: python, pip

Is there a way you can download python packages, without being able to access CMD. As it is blocked. I am trying to get Geocoder.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Have you tried to run *Anaconda prompt* instead of cmd?

Comment: To say it in one sentence: as a developer you need access to the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other than the command line, you can download the package through browser from **https://pypi.org/project/geocoder/#files and install it manually